# Windows kernel ReadProcessMemory() / WriteProcessMemory()?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, kernel-module

It's simple and straightforward in user mode because of those APIs.

How do you read/write specified process's userspace memory from a windows kernel module?

*driver target platform is windows xp/2003*

Comment: You should be accessing the memory in-context during your capture phase, after which point you should operate only on the captured values. Otherwise you have a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 4):

Use NtWriteVirtualMemory / NtReadVirtualMemory to write to other processes - you will need to open a handle to the process first.

Note that if you're already in the process, you can just write directly - for example if you're responding to a DeviceIoControl request from a process you can write directly to user-mode addresses and they will be in the address space of the process that called you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also starting in the world of windows drivers and from what I've read XxxProcessMemory calls NtXxxVirtualMemory in ntdll (R3-UserMode).
The NtXxxVirtualMemory calls the ZwXxxVirtualMemory (R0-KernelMode) also in the ntdll.

I believe you should use the ZwXxxVirtualMemory.

Answer (score 0):

In the krnel, ZwXxx routines are just wrappers around NtXxx ones, telling the kernel that the caller is a kernel mode component, rather than an user application. When a call comes from usermode, the kernel performs additional security checks.

So, use ZwXxx when in the kernel.

An alternative approach for reading/writing memory from/to another process is:

1. obtain address of its process object (PsLookupProcessByProcessId),
2. switch the current thread to its address space (KeStackAttachProcess),
3. perform the operation (read/write...),
4. switch the address space back (KeUnstackDetachProcess),
5. decrement reference count incremented by (1) (ObDereferenceObject).